# How can use a variable as a regex pattern in QT frame work C++

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use a string variable as a Regex pattern. But code can not find matches:

```
QString pattern, m;
QRegularExpression re (pattern);
QRegularExpressionMatch match;
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i;

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  pattern = ui->lineEdit->text();
  k = re.globalMatch(ui->lineEdit_2->text());
  while (i.hasNext()) {
    match = i.next();
    m = m +" "+ match.captured(0);
  }
  ui->label>setText(n); 
}
```

Comment: In your real code, you have set `pattern` to an actual regular expression? Have you [tested](https://regex101.com/) the regex? What is the regex, and what is the string you want to match?

Comment: Construct the regex `re` after that `pattern` change.

Comment: Yes I tested. for example when 'pattern' is 'hi|bye' and string is "hi Harry bye"

Comment: OT (a bit), why won't you use std::regex? New Qt versions already require C++11 so using standard features seems to be better idea than Qt duplicates.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek : `std::regex` probably doesn't play quite as nicely as `QRegularExpression` with `QString` (and he is stuck with `QString` as the result of `text()`).  Also, if everyone else is familiar with `QRegularExpression` why change?  `std::regex` will be subtly different.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yep, converting `QString` → `std::string` and vice versa isn't good idea. And even though IMHO more people know how to use `std::regex` than `QRegularExpression` I understend your reasoning, he actually may make better use of Qt than standard library in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments below

```
QString pattern, m;              // Construct an empty 'pattern'
QRegularExpression re (pattern); // Construct 're' from that empty pattern
QRegularExpressionMatch match;
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i;

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  pattern = ui->lineEdit->text();             // Change 'pattern' - won't have any
                                              // effect on 're' of course.
  k = re.globalMatch(ui->lineEdit_2->text()); // Use the original 're'
  while (i.hasNext()) {
    match = i.next();
    m = m +" "+ match.captured(0);
  }
  ui->label>setText(n); 
}
```

You have to construct `re` *after* you have changed `pattern`:

```
  QString pattern = ui->lineEdit->text(); // Initialize pattern.
  QRegularExpression re(pattern);         // Construct 're' from 'pattern'
  k = re.globalMatch ...
```